# Show that $|3\sin(\theta) + 4\cos(\theta)| \leq 5$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I am not sure how to go about this.

Is it wise to convert the $3\sin(\theta)$ into $\cos$ using trig identities so we only deal with $\cos$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest you to provide your attempts made so far so that we can better help you.

Comment: L'addition sil vous plait!

Comment: Keep in mind this is only true if $\theta$ is real. For $\theta$ complex it's possible for $|3 \sin(\theta) + 4 \cos(\theta)| > 5$

Comment: Hint: Dividing by $5$ gives $|\frac{3}{5} \sin \theta + \frac{4}{5} \cos \theta| \leq 1$ to be proved. It's starting to look like the $\sin(a+b)$ formula, if only those fractions were trig functions of some angle.

Comment: @StefMan In fact, according to the suggestion of aschepler, one has

$$3\sin(\theta) + 4\cos(\theta) = 5\left(\frac{3}{5}\sin(\theta) + \frac{4}{5}\cos(\theta)\right) = 5\sin(\theta + \alpha)$$

where $\alpha = \arcsin(4/5)$.

Comment: More generally, it can be shown that $a \sin(\theta) + b \cos(\theta) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin(\theta + \alpha)$, where $\alpha = \arctan(\frac{b}{a})$.

Comment: Thank you, @aschepler's hint just clicked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y = 3 \sin(\theta) + 4 \cos(\theta) = 5 \left[ \frac{3}{5} \sin(\theta) + \frac{4}{5} \cos(\theta) \right]$.

Now let $\phi = \arctan(\frac{4}{3})$. We also have that $\sin(\phi) = \frac{4}{5}$ and $\cos(\phi) = \frac{3}{5}$.

Remember that $\sin(a+b) = \cos(a)\sin(b)+\sin(a)\cos(b)$, so we can write $y = 5 \left[ \cos(\phi)\sin(\theta) + \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta) \right] = 5 \sin(\phi+\theta)$.

Can you see that $|y| \leq 5$?